# How to change location of the bazel caching area?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to run bazel from a company-installed location.  It decides to use my home directory for some caching and extracting installation files. There is no much space (company policy). So, the question is: how to redirect it to a different location? I could not find much on the web.

```
WARNING: Output base '/home/name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_name/b05102fc551c33214ce89fb43ea90837' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.
Extracting Bazel installation...
FATAL: Failed to extract embedded binaries: Failed to write zipped file '/home/name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_name/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2.tmp.10086/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar': (error: 122): Disk quota exceeded
```

Also, not sure why it thinks that this is NFS. I try to run it onlinux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it: `bazel --output_user_root=<loc>` fixes the issue.